# How to get the list of all pthread Ids from main thread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to get all the running pthread_t Ids currently running inside the process.
Is it possible to get it dynamically in my c program?. 
Is there any pthread API to do so ?

I need this list of thread IDs to send signal to each of the thread using pthread_kill().

Comment: Surely you created them, so you can store them as you spawn them?

Comment: Yes, But I am using an open source. Storing these Ids when created and removing them when thread stops is tedious job.

Comment: Thread could be created by any mean and not just through pthread interface. So process is not aware of how children are created.